# How to let the child component fill up the parent div container in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my scenario, I want the custom component(AntVX6Comp) fill the parent component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/14m7hi

but I cannot fill up the parent in my component:
[image]

my requirement is fill the parent component(or div container) don't use special number, because the container size will change.

in the Graph API, I only can give specific number as params:

```
 const graph = new Graph({
      container: containerRef.current || undefined,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      grid: true,
      async: true,
      background: {
        color: "#F2F7FA",
      },
    });
```

it cannot use like `100%` to do with it. only number and undefined type, I also tried to use `undefined`, but not luck.

so how to let it fill up the parent component in React?

Answer (score 0):

if you can't use **100%** value for the width and height, I suggest calculating the width and height of the parent container using javascript and set the values dynamically on the container element

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dimensions to the parent's dimensions by getting the `scrollHeight`/`clientHeight` and `scrollWidth`/`clientWidth` from the `containerRef`.

```
width: containerRef.current?.scrollWidth || 200,
height: containerRef.current?.scrollHeight || 300,
```

The `||` part is for a default length.

Comment: It says: `Property "scrollWidth" does not exist on type "never" ts(2339)`

Comment: the type of your ref should be `HTMLInputElement`